# sklearn n_jobs!=1 not parallelizing on Windows

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, joblib

I'm trying to take advantage of the parallelizing options available in sklearn, but setting n_jobs!=1 doesn't seem to start any parallel process... When looking at the computer performance, only 12.5% of CPU capacity is being used (I've got an Intel Core i7, 4 cores, 8 threads; that is, it's using just one thread...).

I've tried with different functions of sklearn and importing my function (the one that uses the sklearn function) from a separate module, but still the same. I also found many other answers but were specifically for Linux, while I'm using Windows 10. In addition, I've tried this n_jobs functionality on Linux with no errors, so I guess it must be something between joblib and Windows/Intel, but I have no idea of what it may be... I read once something like joblib had some problems handling Intel virtual cores on Windows, but not sure if, being that the case, there's already a solution or not.

The particular line of code I'm using is:

```py
labels = MeanShift(bandwidth=25,bin_seeding=True,n_jobs=4).fit_predict(X)
```

where X is a numpy matrix of 6557436x3.

I guess CPU processing capacity should be 50% when executing the code, but, as I said, it is only 12.5%...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Except for the apparent core usage, I can replicate similar behavior, also on Windows 10. Calling `ElasticNetCV.fit()`. `n_jobs=None` is the fastest (engages 50% of CPU on Task Manager), then `n_jobs=1` then `n_jobs=2` and so on progressively slower until `n_jobs=4`. `n_jobs=-1` is slower than them all. All but `n_jobs=None` seem to max out CPU usage at 100% but are progressively slower than the next. Intel Core i7-7700 @ 4.2GHz. 4 cores and 8 logical processors. Using python 3.6.10 and sklearn 0.20.1. Not particularly big problem set. 1000 samples, 30 features, 10 L1_ratios.